# Can not reset form back after submit post jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I tried to insert the form data by using post jquery, to process the data successfully into the database, but the problem is how to reset the form back as before without reloading the form, so the hidden does not reappear after I change option `$(".access")` ?

```
<button type="button" id="add-user" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add user</button>
</br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="from-user" style="display: none">
    <form id="form-add" class="form-horizontal">        
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="nama">
              <label for="nama">Name * :</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" type="text"  required />
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="nama">
              <label for="nama">Address * :</label>
              <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control" type="text" required />
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="view-access">
              <label for="access">Access * :</label>
                <select name="access" id="access" class="access form-control" required>
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="0">Admin</option>
                    <option value="1">Staff</option>
                    <option value="2">Employees</option>
                    <option value="3">User</option>
                </select>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="view-section">
              <label for="section">Section * :</label>
                <select name="section" id="section" class="form-control" required>
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="0">Hotel</option>
                    <option value="1">Cafe</option>
                    <option value="2">Restaurant</option>
                </select>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="view-status">
              <label for="status">Status * :</label>
                <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control" required>
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="0">Active</option>
                    <option value="1">Deactive</option>
                </select>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="sub">
              <button type="button" id="submit"  class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
    </form> 
    </div>  
</div>  

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#add-user").click(function() {
        $(".from-user").toggle("slow"); 
    });


    $(".access").change(function(){     
        var value=$(this).val();
        if(value == 2 || value == 3){               
            $('.view-section').hide();
            $('.view-status').hide();   
        }else if(value == 1){
            $('.view-section').show();
            $('.view-status').hide();               
        }else{  
            $('.view-section').show();
            $('.view-status').show();           
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#submit', function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var btn_button = $(this);
            $.post(base_url+"add.php", data, function(data){
                $(".from-user").toggle("slow", function(){
                    $("#form-add")[0].reset();
                    $(".from-user").load(location.href + ".from-user");
                }); 
            });
    });
})  
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#form-add")[0].reset();` looks to be working fine in this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/jYmKxg)

Comment: Thanks @LouysPatriceBessette, it looks good in codepen as i expected but it does not work on my script? does anyone clash his jquery script? I use the Gentelella template because of it

Comment: Look for errors in [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337)...

Comment: I've seen in the console there is no error, only the form does not return to the beginning when there is a hidden

Comment: Maybe your `$.post()` isn't calling back... Is `base_url` defined?

Comment: yes I have defined its base_url

Comment: Add a `console.log("HEY! I'm here");` in that `.post()` callback...

Comment: I have tried and appeared on the console

Comment: mmm... Double check your "form-xyz" and "from-xyz" in id and classes... It certainly is a typo somewhere.

Comment: I just taught about that... Mabe your `base_url` and `data` is defined... But is it within the `$(document).ready()` ? Try to console.log() them in the `.post()` callback.

Comment: Your  post `data` appears undefined in `$.post`